# Wrong Date inserted in Date column

Tags: java, database, date

I have a strange situation.

In my application we are inserting a record with the current date (MM/dd/yyyy) when users access something in the application.

Sometimes the date is getting inserted with a wrong value that isn't the current date. (Ie: '21/09/2014', '13/09/2180', '22/08/2179'). We are using JPA to insert the record from JAVA. Please help me to find out the issue or solution for this.

Below is the code, where I am preparing/passing the value for Domain object.

```
Date curDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
UserAccessObj.setAccessedDate(sdf.parse( sdf.format( curDate ) ));
```

Here **setAccessedDate**(Date) is java.util.Date setter method in domain object.

So, what might be the issue? I am not able to trace the issue.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What's the point formatting and parsing it back to Date object?

Comment: is it posible for you print out sdf.parse( sdf.format( curDate ) ) before inserting to database?

Comment: Why do you convert `curDat` (which is already a `Date`) to String and then back to a `Date`? `UserAccessObj.setAccessedDate(curDate);` seems to be what you want.

Comment: I assume the format/parse is to bin the time component of Date

Comment: Database is Oracle 10g. and why formatting is, I have a requirement to store the value in a specific format(not complete Date with timestams, etc..,). that's why we are using formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
UserAccessObj.setAccessedDate(sdf.parse(sdf.format(curDate)));
```

Try this:

```
UserAccessObj.setAccessedDate(curDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
sdf.parse( sdf.format( curDate ) )
```

strictly necessary ? You're taking a date, converting it to a string, and then parsing it as a date ? I suspect you're doing this to get rid of the time component of the (misleadingly-named) `Date` object ? I think using the `Calendar` class as per [the answer in this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/497096/java/java/Remove-time-part-java-util) is faster/safer. The best answer is to use the [Joda-Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

I don't know if it's causing your problem, but it's adding unnecessary complexity. Note also that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe, and if the above code shares an instance of a `SimpleDateFormat`  that would definitely account for peculiar behaviour. Again, Joda-Time provides thread-safety in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do is use Calendar object to get the **current system time**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and then convert it into the SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

and then you have your own code

```
UserAccessObj.setAccessedDate(sdf.parse( sdf.format( curDate ) ));
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Save the input date into DB in this format : **"yyyy-MM-dd"**. Correct date will be saved.